# using ubuntu on a flash drive in windows 8

Tags: dual-boot

I have a new HP pavilion G6 2240NR with 64 bit AMD6and

a factory install of windows8 and would like to run Ubuntu from a flash drive without installing it and be able to switch back a forth.Has anyone
done this or know how?I have tried the Netboot way described on there site but it just booted back to win 8.I guess what I need to know is first what version of Ubuntu to use and how to get it on the flash drive and to get the drive to dual boot in win 8.Idealy I would like it so when I had the flash drive in and started it it would boot to Ubuntu and to boot back to win 8 with it out.My problem has been there is a lot of different info on line that I read but thay all are a bit different than what I want to do.....Thank you also my experience with Ubuntu is only loading it on a laptop from a disc ...Wayne

Answer (score 1):

1) In your UEFI(BIOS) settings, change the boot order to have USB
    before the hard disk. 
2) If you want to utilize the Windows
    partitions in any way, also turn off "fast Boot", to ensure Windows
    shuts down completely instead of hibernating. Leave secure boot
    enabled. 
3) Use unetbootin on Windows to create a USB live media
    from a 64 bit Ubuntu, either 12.04.2, 12.10, or 13.04. 
4) Edit the
    usb's /boot/grub/grub.cfg file to add the word "persistent" to the
    linux boot line (bug 1159016) if you want to save your settings on
    the stick (highly recommended). 
5)Insert stick and boot. 
6) If that doesn't work, complain to HP about their incompetent implementation
    of UEFI.

Comment: Thank,while I was looking through unebootin a stumbled across a new part that gave the persistent info and also said that in the new versions it was already added.I downloaded 13.04/64 live followed the uefi/bios inst.and also turned off safe boot and it worked great.I put the usd fd in hit restart and have Ubuntu,turn it off pull out the drive and turn it and I'm back to windows 8 great stuff and thanks again for the help...............

Answer (score 1):

You can create Ubuntu Live USB from easy step using Startup Disk Creator, after that plug USB and restart your machine, make your first boot device to USB, save change and restart, now you can ubuntu live without install

[image]